# Можно ли оптимизировать SQL запрос прямым форматированием?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, оптимизация, sqlite3

Пример работающего, но не оптимального кода по созданию и заполнению БД SQLite.

Пока стиль написания кода далек от идеала,  увы, мешает старая школа программирования. Конструктивная критика приветствуется.

P.S. Программа, принятая за основу (подсчет слов) не моя. Это учебный материал с [Метанита](https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/5.4.php).

```
"""
Программа подсчета слов в файле
и вывод данных в базу формата SQLite,
встроенную в Python
"""
import os
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("testSqlite.db") # или :memory: чтобы сохранить 
                                        # в RAM
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Создание таблицы
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE slova (slovo text, kolvo integer)""")
symbols ="йцукенгшщзхъэждлорпавыфячсмитьбюё"

def get_words(filename):

    with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as file:
        text = file.read()
    text = text.replace("\n", " ")
    text = text.replace(",", "").replace(".", "").replace("?", 
"").replace("!", "")
    text = text.lower()
    words = text.split()
    words.sort()
    return words


def get_words_dict(words):
    words_dict = dict()

    for word in words:
        ps = word[0]
        pk = word[-1]
        if (symbols.find(pk) != -1) and (symbols.find(ps) != -1) and 
len(word)<15 :
            if word in words_dict:
                words_dict[word] = words_dict[word] + 1
            else:
                words_dict[word] = 1
    return words_dict


def main():
    filename = input("Введите путь к файлу: ")
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        print("Указанный файл не существует")
    else:
        words = get_words(filename)
        words_dict = get_words_dict(words)

        print("Все использованные слова:")
        for word in words_dict:
             print(word.ljust(20), words_dict[word])
             sl = word.ljust(20).replace("'","")
             kol= int(words_dict[word])
             mSql="""INSERT INTO slova
                     VALUES ('slovo', 'kolvo')"""
             mySql_insert_query = mSql.replace("slovo"," 
{zsl}".format(zsl=sl.rstrip()))
             mSql = mySql_insert_query
             mySql_insert_query = mSql.replace("kolvo"," 
{zkol}".format(zkol=kol))
             cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query)
             conn.commit()
        print("Кол-во слов: %d" % len(words))
        print("Кол-во уникальных слов: %d" % len(words_dict))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под словами _"оптимизировать SQL запрос прямым форматированием"_?

Comment: Тут обходной вариант: cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query)
Тело SQL запроса обработано коряво,  при помощи костылей.

Comment: 0xdb: cпасибо за правки. Зачетно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того чтобы эффективно вставить множество записей / строк в SQL таблицу следует использовать метод [cursor.executemany(sql, seq_of_parameters)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects) вкупе с *параметризированным* SQL запросом:

```
def insert_words(cursor, word_dict):
    records = [(k,v) for k,v in word_dict.items()]
    sql = """INSERT INTO slova VALUES(?, ?)"""
    # notice the usage of parameters: ^  ^ 
    cursor.executemany(sql, records)


# calling "insert_words(cursor, word_dict)"
insert_words(cursor, word_dict)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это то, что и хотел.

Comment: Все рабочее. Единственное - поправил "очепяточку" вместо word_dict у меня в программе words_dict.
Скорость обработки на порядок увеличилась.
Кстати, если кому надо формирование базы слов русского языка, то на большом количестве книжных файлов можно набрать полный языковый вариант. Гоняю программку на файлах fb2-формата. И xml-разметка в этих файлах не мешает выборке слов.